# Switching tone on and off at 120 bpm not working

Tags: fpga, verilog, clock, sound

I am trying to make a design that toggles a sound at a rate of 120 BPM (once every .5 seconds), and I am using a 50 MHz clock. Here's the tone module:

```
module tone(
input clk, 
input enable,
output reg speaker);

parameter clkdivider = 25000000/440/2;

reg [14:0] counter;
always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) counter <= clkdivider-1; else counter <= counter-1;

always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) speaker <= enable ? ~speaker : 0;
endmodule
```

and here's the toggling module:

```
module lockstep_main(input clk, output speaker);

reg enable;

tone(.clk(clk), .enable(enable), .speaker(speaker));

parameter beat = 50000000/2;
reg [14:0] counter;
always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) counter <= beat-1; else counter <= counter-1;

always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) enable <= ~enable;

endmodule
```

As it is, the design doesn't work properly, just causing the speaker to emit garbled tones. Also, if I try setting the enable register to 1 initially and not changing it, I still get no sound. What could be the issue here?

Comment: You have no reset configuration so the registers will start off full of garbage or 'X'.

Comment: I tried adding an initial set to 0, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50000000/2 requires 25 bits, not 15 (log base 2 of 25000000 is 24.575, the ceil of that is 25).  In the second module, counter gets set to 30783 instead of 25000000 so the 'BPM' is ~97456 instead of 120.

Comment: Thank you so much! I misread a powers of 2 table, causing me to think 15 bits was sufficient.